# What is the height when the ball is thrown vertically upward with air resistance??

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations

A ball is thrown vertically upward with u velocity. There is air resistance and the air resistance is directly proportional to square of ball's velocity,u. Find the height which the ball can reach. 
I started with,
$$a=-g-{{k\over m}u^2},~~~~~~~~~
 {d^2x\over dt^2} = -g - {k\over m}\left({dx\over dt}\right)^2$$

Is it true? and How can I solve this differential equation?

Comment: Let $\lambda = \frac{k}{m}$, we have
$$x'' = -g - \lambda x'^2 
\iff (\lambda x)'' + (\lambda x')^2 + \lambda g = 0
\implies (e^{\lambda x})'' + \lambda g (e^{\lambda x}) = 0$$
If $x(0) = 0$ and $x'(0) = v$, the ODE has solution
$$e^{\lambda x} = \frac{\sin(\sqrt{\lambda g} t + \phi)}{\sin\phi}
\quad\text{ where }\quad \lambda v = \sqrt{\lambda g}\cot\phi$$
When $x$ reaches its maximum value $h$, we have
$$e^{\lambda h} = \frac{1}{\sin\phi} \quad\implies\quad  h = \frac{1}{2\lambda}\log\left(1 + \frac{\lambda v^2}{g}\right)$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HINT...since you are looking for the height not the time, write $$a=v\frac{dv}{dx}=-(g+\frac kmv^2)$$

Comment: Thanks. You are right.

Answer (score 0):

**HINT**

Yes your set up is correct indeed we have that

- $a=-g-\frac k m \cdot v^2 \implies \frac{dv}{dt}=-g-\frac k m v^2 \implies \frac{v'(t)}{-g-\frac k m v^2}dt=dt$

which can be integrated (see [**here**](https://philosophicalmath.wordpress.com/2017/10/21/terminal-velocity-derivation/) for the details).